# iOS Collectionviewcell multiple items and dynamic height

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView cell, which has multiple items[image]

I need to implement its dynamic height depending on the data of 1st bold label
I have tried multiple code snippets but not working for my case.
as most of them are checking a specific label height and assigning it to the cell size..
Thanks

Comment: Calculate the height of the bold label with its text then add the remaining default height with it.

Comment: what is wrong, for negative mark?
isn't it clear?
one may leave his reason

Comment: I don't want to calculate the height, i want it to be automatic.
as it slows down the collection view

Comment: As you think it will not slowdown the collection view. The calculation process will not take that much time

Answer (score 0):

I have written this function in Xamarin.iOS to calculate the height of cell. 
Hope this will help you.

```
CGRect GetRectOfItemNameLabel(ActivityTaskModel item , UITableView tableView)
        {
            nfloat width = tableView.Frame.Width;
            UIStringAttributes attrs1 = new UIStringAttributes ();
            attrs1.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 17);
            CGRect frameName = ((NSString)item.TaskDescription).GetBoundingRect (new CGSize (width, 100000), NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attrs1, null);
            return frameName;
    }
```

Make sure you don't provide any height constraint to that label/TextView.

Note : If your text is larger then rather than using Label use TextView